# C error: request for member error when i compile

Tags: c, debugging, struct, compiler-errors

I've got many error my first compile in C. I'm new in C programming. How can i solve this problem and why this happened?

My source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct n{
    int x;
    n *next;
};
typedef n node;

int main(){
    node *root;
    root = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    root->x = 10;
    root->next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    root->next->x = 20;
    printf("%d", root->next->x);
    node *iter;
    iter = root;
    return 0;

}
```

And I've got these errors when i compile my code 'gcc LinkedList1.c -o LinkedList1;

```
LinkedList1.c:13:9: error: request for member ‘x’ in something not a structure or union
     root->x = 10;
         ^
LinkedList1.c:14:9: error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union
     root->next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
         ^
LinkedList1.c:15:9: error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union
     root->next->x = 20;
         ^
LinkedList1.c:16:22: error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union
     printf("%d", root->next->x);
```

**But there is no problem when i compile with g++**

Comment: It seems that this code has a more fundamental error (http://ideone.com/NMwM1T): `prog.c:6:5: error: unknown type name ‘n': n *next;`.

Comment: this `n *next;` should be `struct n *next;`

Comment: `typedef n node;` -->> `typedef struct n node;` (and a strong advice **not** to use typedefs, until you need them. They are confusing, and seldomly needed)

Comment: Always start reading compiler messages at the *top*. Never ignore the first message in favor of a later message just because you think you understand one more than another. Later messages are frequently *side effects* of an earlier message. Fix the first, and later errors will often just go away by themselves.

Comment: Is there a problem when you compile with javac ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C and C++ differ in the meaning of a `struct`-definition in the aspect that C++ automatically introduces a new type name named after the class/struct/union, whereas C does *NOT* introduce such a type name automatically. Confer, for example, this [online C++ draft standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class#1):

> **9. Classes**
>
> (1) A class is a type. Its name becomes a class-name within
>   its scope.
>
> (2) A class-name is inserted into the scope in which it is declared
>   immediately after the class-name is seen. The class-name is also
>   inserted into the scope of the class itself. ...

So in C++, `struct n { n *next };` introduces a new type named `n`, which is immediately available even in the `struct`-definition at hand, such that `n *next` already refers to an existing type. (Note that a `struct` and a `class` in C++ are almost identical).

The C-standard is not that clear in describing which part of the specification actually is the type name (cf, for example, this [online C draft standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p7)):

> **6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers**
>
> (7) ... The keywords struct and union indicate that the type being
>   specified is, respectively, a structure type or a union type.
>
> (8) The presence of a struct-declaration-list in a
>   struct-or-union-specifier declares a new type, within a translation
>   unit. ... The type is incomplete until immediately after the } that terminates the list, and complete thereafter.

But actually `struct n { ....}` introduces a new type that is identified through keyword `struct` and the name `n`, i.e. through `struct n`.

Side note: An interesting/funny thing might be that even a reference to `struct n` in the structure definition at first hand refers to an incomplete type, i.e. `struct n` is a forward declaration right until the enclosing `}`. Only together with the definition of forward declarations for structs, which have been introduced to allow circular references between structs, a `struct n *next` becomes valid.

It is common practice then to "manually" introduce an alias by the means of a `typedef`, i.e. `typedef struct n node`, such that `node` alone has the same meaning as `struct n`. And often the alias is defined together with the structure itself. So your code for C could work as follows:

```
typedef struct n{
    int x;
    struct n *next;
} node;
```

Comment: A - for thoroughness and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In C to when you want to use a struct type prepending `struct` to type name is mandatory. A common practice is to define a type alias for structs in order to avoid doing this all the time. So your code should look like this:

```
struct n{
    int        x;
    struct n * next;
};
typedef struct n node;
```

In C++ there is no need to prepend `struct` all the time (or define extra type aliases) so the same code compiles fine with g++.

Answer (score 0):

Change your struct definition to:

```
struct n {
    int x;
    struct n *next;
};
typedef struct n node;
```

where I prepended `struct` keyword before `n`. You have to do that, but you are probably confused with C++, which doesn't require you to do so.

Answer (score 0):

// This compiles as a C program and gives value 20 as the output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct node {
  int x;
  struct node *next;
};

int main()
{
    struct node *root;

    root = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    root->x = 10;
    root->next = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    root->next->x = 20;
    printf("%d", root->next->x);
    struct node *iter;
    iter = root;
}
```

C language requires `struct` keyword when referring to a struct variable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm sure what you say is true, but unless you explain *why* your code works and the original code doesn't, then what's the point? This isn't the place to play "spot the difference."

Comment: @RobKennedy Thanks Rob! A required explanations has been added.